# all parameters correct? but Contact Form submitting, but not sending email through

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

I am trying to set up a form on my site to allow the standard "Contact me". But when it is filled out and submitted, nothing comes through to my mail. I have done a :

```
<?php
mail('info@ashlutonphotography.com.au','Test mail','The mail function is working!');
echo 'Mail sent!';
?>
```

Which works fine, but my form doesnt work with this php:

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$_email='info@ashlutonphotography.com.au';
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@ashlutonphotography.com.au"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

This is the contact_me.js

```
$(function() {

    $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            // Prevent spam click and default submit behaviour
            $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", true);
            event.preventDefault();

            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Enable button & show success message
                    $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", false);
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            })
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});

// When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});`
```

With this being the HTML:

```
<section id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2>Contact us</h2>
                    <p><img src="PENCIL.png" width="709" height="93" alt="pen"></p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">

                    <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label>Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label>Email Address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label>Phone Number</label>
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label>Message</label>
                                <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div id="success"></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Any ideas folks?

Please and thank you.

Ash

Comment: check what mail() returns - check the server mail logs

Comment: Not sure if it's the problem, but I noticed that there is no linefeed on your headers. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 1):

From your code:

```
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```

There is no `$to` var.

Comment: Hi Yassuki, so if i change that to `mail($_email,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);`

Answer (score 0):

On your php script I don't see where the `$to` variable was assigned maybe you meant `$_email`

Comment: Do you mean   mail `($_email,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);`

Comment: yes try mail($_email,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

Comment: Have updated to say that, and still no good. :(

Comment: i have even tried changing the `$to = 'info@ashlutonphotography.com.au' and  `mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);` still nothing :(

Comment: can you get to your php script from a browser using the url that you are providing on the ajax call?  `././mail/contact_me.php`

Comment: I just get a "No Arguments Provided" if i just try and get to it directly

Comment: I also just tried 

`mail( 'info@ashlutonphotography.com.au', $to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);`

To try and hard code it to send there, but it didnt work either :(